# OxygenOS 9 request read service message permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, runtime-permissions, miui, oneplusone

Oxygen OS 9 running on OnePlus phones currently (6 and 6T) has started to have segregated app permissions like Xiaomi MIUI. I am unable to get any technique to request permission to "read service message" on Oxygen OS 9 and above. I have read all available pieces of documentation and resources on Oxygen OS but have been unable to find procedure to request "read service message" permission and open the relevant setting page.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to find some reference by OnePlus for their updated permissions but couldn't. Maybe you could try the following approach : 
1- connect your device to USB Debugging, then run

`adb shell 'pm list packages -f'`.

This will give you a list of packages installed on the system. 
2- In the previous output, search for packages that are developed by OnePlus. 
3- Run this command for each of the packages found in the previous step

```
adb shell dumpsys package packagename | grep permission
```

This command will give you the list of permission required by the package, with some luck you should be able to identify the new permissions.